# Unplug computer during thunderstorms?

Tags: power, surge-protection

I once heard from a friend of mine that it's good practice to disconnect your computer and tv during a thunderstorm to avoid damage from electrical surges caused by lightning strikes. It kind of makes sense, but nobody else that I've asked does this.
Do you unplug your equipment during thunderstorms?
If you have a UPS, do you trust that it can handle a lightning strike or do you unplug it as well?